# top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop-2); not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

in my local i have IE 10, this Css 
"`top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop-2);`"
runs perfectly. when i host on client system, in **IE11** the top expression is not working.

While inspecting the css is striked out.

My application designed only for IE. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have answered this question as asked below. If you are looking for alternative methods to do what you need, please edit this question with a more detailed sample of code and a description of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> CSS expressions no longer supported for the Internet zone [in Internet Explorer 11]

Generally speaking, you should avoid expressions given their minimal browser support and performance issues.